# Displaying an image from internal storage from android phone with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I have made a very simple app to take a picture using camera x, with a viewfinder and it displays the image taken in the same activity
I am trying to get all the images taken from the internal storage and display them in another activity in the app with a recycler view
Im fine with recycler views, and I can use one with external Api's to display images and data but I just cannot figure out how to get the images from the internal storage, and add them to a list to display in the recycler view, Ive tried checking documentation but im getting nowhere, all I need is a simple code which will allow me to display the images as a thumbnail

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

private val TAG = "Snap"
private val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
private val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    btnSnap.setOnClickListener {
        takePhoto()
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        startCamera()
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
        )
    }
    outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                        permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray ) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        startCamera()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        finish()
    }
}

private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = getInstance(this)

    //add listener to the ProcessCameraProvider
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
            it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())}

        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        try {
            //unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview,
                imageCapture)
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}

private fun takePhoto() {    val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

    val photoFile = File(outputDirectory, SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT,
        Locale.UK).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

    val outputOpts = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

    imageCapture.takePicture(outputOpts,
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object :
            ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }
            //save the photo to the file and display on screen
            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                imgSnap.setImageURI(savedUri)
            }
        })
}

private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
    val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
        File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
    }
    return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists()) mediaDir else filesDir
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [link](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView) that provides you the better overview about using RecyclerView..

And in your bind view holder method in your adapter you can use this code to get the images from the storage and show it into your recyclerview as thumbnail.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myImage.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

You can learn more about the getting the images from storage [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-an-image-file-in-internal-storage-in-android).

Comment: kindly upvote the answer if it helps you and it eill help others to get the idea about the topic. thanks 

Comment: Decoding bitmaps inside onBindViewHolder method will result in performance issues. Use ContentProviders along with scaled images for displaying in a list.